Why does my WordPress site show "Certificate is not trusted" on Apple devices?
I have a WordPress site that was hacked a few months ago. I cleaned up the site and resolved the security issues, but since then, I’ve encountered a problem when trying to access the site from Apple devices.
Whenever I try to open the site on Safari (tested on iPhone, iPad, and Mac), I get error messages stating that a certificate is not trusted. The exact error varies across devices. For example:

"The Cisco Umbrella Root CA certificate is not trusted."
"The Fortinet Root certificate is not trusted."

Here’s some additional information:

The site works perfectly on machines running Windows or Android devices when accessed via Chrome or Firefox.
The site is hosted on shared hosting, and it uses a Let's Encrypt SSL certificate.
I’ve checked the SSL certificate via online tools, and everything seems fine.
I suspect the issue might be related to Apple devices or Safari, but I’m not sure how to troubleshoot further.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue before? What steps should I take to resolve this error?

It looks like you are trying do do this from behind a site that does a man-in-the-middle attack to intercept HTTPS traffic - this is not uncommon at workplaces with a decent size IT staff, as they may want to track what there users are doing, and scan for Virii and malware before it enters the network.
If this is the case, your devices need to include their root certificate so they can intercept the traffic and pass it on to you without error.   It would seem that this root certificate has not been installed (or maybe was installed but was not updated and expired) on your iDevices.
We know that something is failing to MITM the connection because Fortinet and Cisco Umbrella are both associated with firewalls - and obviously your iDevices are not seeing the real LetsEncrypt cert - which would be expected in a MITM attack - even one used for legitimate reason.
